# Flutter Navigator get Data from replaced route

Tags: flutter, navigator, flutter-navigation

im trying to solve a problem i got where i have an await waiting for data on a navigator.push the data is null

[image]

```
await Navigator.pushNamed(context, UdaLogSelector.id); //HomeScreen

Navigator.PushNamedReplacement(context, NewLogScreen.id); //EntryyScreen

Navigator.pop(context, 'Log'); //LogEntryScreen
```

when i replace the SelectEntry screen with Push and Replace the await listening on the HomeScreen gets Fired and it is Null because i need the Data that is sent on the Navigator.pop on the LogEntry screen,

what is the correct way or replacing a screen and being able to send databack to the orignal screen on the stack?

im able to pop back to the Homescreen, but i am unable to get the databack that was sent in the Pop method, i need this data to trigger a snackbar

Updated Code

```
//HomeScreen
                      RawMaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          final data = await Navigator.pushNamed(
                                  context, UdaLogSelector.id)
                          print(data);
                          if (data != null) {
                          }

//UdaSelectorScreen
                GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, NewLogScreen.id);
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Enter Log',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, UdaScreen.id);
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Enter Uda',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              )

//NewLogScreen
Navigator.pop(context, 'Log');

//UdaSreen
Navigator.pop(context, 'Uda');
```

Comment: post your real code - i have no idea what you mean by `Navigator.PushNamedReplacement(context, NewLogScreen.id);`

Comment: @pskink i have added the code i am using for navigating through the stack